# New logo for the blog in the side bar

Tags: discussion, design, logo

The logo for the blog in the sidebar is the same as the logo for Meta.SE (here):

<kbd>[image: sidebar]</kbd>

Please could a new logo be used here? While it isn't a massive issue, it does momentarily confuse me, and the blog is certainly different to Meta...

Feel free to post your suggestions for a logo as an answer - but by no means will it be used - if the logo is even changed!